# How can I simulate variables, loops, and concatenations to work together in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I am stuck with the limitations of both SQLite and the design of some of its tables. Here's what I'd like to achieve:

1. Create a variable to track the number of iterations of a loop. Then use this variable to help create unique table rows during the loop. Also insert it as the literal count value in a record.
2. Concatenate said variable to existing strings to create unique IDs that can be referenced multiple times.
3. Loop code using the previous variable to track iterations, and the previous concatenations as IDs for inserting new rows for every loop. 255 loops is an arbitrary number, I doubt I'd need 255 loops in 99.9% of cases, but want to avoid failure in the cases where they are needed. I am realistically looking at 50 loops minimum, with 100 as a rare maximum. 200 would likely be closer to the true maximum outlier number. 255 is just to be safe.

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;

WHILE @cnt < 256
BEGIN
    @seyield = 'BUILDING_STOCK_EXCHANGE_YIELD_' + @cnt;
    @secitizens = 'BUILDING_STOCK_EXCHANGE_CITIZENS_' + @cnt;
    @secount = 'COUNT_CITIZENS_' + @cnt;

    INSERT INTO
        BuildingModifiers (BuildingType, ModifierId)
    VALUES
        ('BUILDING_STOCK_EXCHANGE', @seyield);

    INSERT INTO
        Modifiers (ModifierId, ModifierType, RunOnce, Permanent, SubjectRequirementSetId)
    VALUES
        (@seyield, 'MODIFIER_BUILDING_YIELD_CHANGE', 0, 0, @secitizens);

    INSERT INTO
        ModifierArguments (ModifierID, Name, Value)
    VALUES
        (@seyield, 'BuildingType', 'BUILDING_STOCK_EXCHANGE'),
        (@seyield, 'Amount', '2'),
        (@seyield, 'YieldType', 'YIELD_GOLD');

    INSERT INTO
        RequirementSets(RequirementSetId, RequirementSetType)
    VALUES
        (@secitizens, 'REQUIREMENT_TEST_ALL');

    INSERT INTO
        RequirementSetRequirements(RequirementSetId, RequirementId)
    VALUES
        (@secitizens, @secount);

    INSERT INTO
        Requirements(RequirementId, RequirementType)
    VALUES
        (@secount, 'REQUIREMENT_COLLECTION_ATLEAST');

    INSERT INTO
        RequirementArguments(RequirementId, Name, Value)
    VALUES
        (@secount, 'CollectionType', 'COLLECTION_CITY_PLOT_YIELDS'),
        (@secount, 'Count', @cnt);

   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

Of course this does not work due to the limitations of SQLite.

Are there any valid workarounds to this?

I know of one, but is almost unfeasible: Leave out the loop, variable, and concatenations, and manually copy and paste this code bloc, manually changing the relevant fields each time. However, this would require 255 copy and pastes multiplied by around 8 or 9 times for each different BUILDING_TYPE I need to attach rows to. I'd rather not do this if there is a faster and more efficient way!

Comment: As far as I am aware SQLite does not support variables or procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) and the use of a temporary table:

```
drop table if exists temp.temptable;
create temporary table temptable(cnt int, seyield text, secitizens text, secount text);

with
  recursive constants as (
    select 
      'BUILDING_STOCK_EXCHANGE_YIELD_' seyield,
      'BUILDING_STOCK_EXCHANGE_CITIZENS_' secitizens,
      'COUNT_CITIZENS_' secount  
  ),
  numbers as (
    select 1 cnt
    from constants
    union all
    select cnt + 1 from numbers
    where cnt < 255
  ),
  cte as (
    select
      n.cnt cnt,
      c.seyield || n.cnt seyield,
      c.secitizens || n.cnt secitizens,
      c.secount || n.cnt secount 
    from numbers n cross join constants c
  )  

insert into temptable
select * from cte;

INSERT INTO BuildingModifiers (BuildingType, ModifierId)
SELECT 'BUILDING_STOCK_EXCHANGE', seyield FROM temptable;

INSERT INTO Modifiers (ModifierId, ModifierType, RunOnce, Permanent, SubjectRequirementSetId)
SELECT seyield, 'MODIFIER_BUILDING_YIELD_CHANGE', 0, 0, secitizens FROM temptable;

INSERT INTO ModifierArguments (ModifierID, Name, Value)
SELECT seyield, 'BuildingType', 'BUILDING_STOCK_EXCHANGE' FROM temptable
UNION ALL
SELECT seyield, 'Amount', '2' FROM temptable
UNION ALL
SELECT seyield, 'YieldType', 'YIELD_GOLD' FROM temptable;

INSERT INTO RequirementSets(RequirementSetId, RequirementSetType)
SELECT secitizens, 'REQUIREMENT_TEST_ALL' FROM temptable;

INSERT INTO RequirementSetRequirements(RequirementSetId, RequirementId)
SELECT secitizens, secount FROM temptable;

INSERT INTO Requirements(RequirementId, RequirementType)
SELECT secount, 'REQUIREMENT_COLLECTION_ATLEAST' FROM temptable;

INSERT INTO RequirementArguments(RequirementId, Name, Value)
SELECT secount, 'CollectionType', 'COLLECTION_CITY_PLOT_YIELDS' FROM temptable
UNION ALL
SELECT secount, 'Count', cnt FROM temptable;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hnVTs2W193zHNDfE7LiUts/6).